# How to disable and undisable certain checkboxes depending on whether a checkbox is checked or unchecked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble getting a bit of code working. I'm using HTML and javascript.

I've stripped everything out to make sure something weird wasn't stopping it from working.

I'll try and word it step by step using the ids for the checkboxes in my form.

- When ac_0 is unchecked ac_1, ac_2 and ac_3 are disabled and unchecked.
- When ac_4 is unchecked ac_5, ac_6 and ac_7 are disabled and unchecked.
- When ac_8 is unchecked ac_9, ac_10, ac_11 and ac_12 are disabled and unchecked.
- When ac_1 is unchecked ac_2 and ac_3 are disabled and unchecked.
- When ac_5 is unchecked ac_6 and ac_7 are disabled and unchecked.
- When ac_9 is unchecked ac_10 and ac_11 are disabled and unchecked.
- For ac_2 and ac_3 to not be disabled then ac_0 has to be checked first then ac_1.
- For ac_6 and ac_7 to not be disabled then ac_4 has to be checked first then ac_5.
- For ac_10 and ac_11 to not be disabled then ac_8 has to be checked first then ac_9.

This form is to be populated from a database so when the page loads it needs to check the status of the check box and deal with it accordingly.

I may need to add further groups to the form so I'm trying to make it easy to add more checkboxes if I need to.

Currently I have got it close to working except when you uncheck/check ac_0, ac_4 or ac_8 it's not working correctly.

- When you uncheck ac_0, ac_4 or ac_8 it works correctly the correct checkboxes disable.
- When you check ac_0 it undisables all of the corresponding checkboxes when ac_2 and ac_3 should remain disabled because ac_1 is unchecked.
- When you check ac_4 it undisables all of the corresponding checkboxes when ac_6 and ac_7 should remain disabled because ac_5 is unchecked.
- When you check ac_8 it undisables all of the corresponding checkboxes when ac_10 and ac_11 should remain disabled because ac_9 is unchecked.

If you check and uncheck ac_1 it starts working correctly until you uncheck and check ac_0 again and the issue happens again. The same happens with with the other groups of checkboxes.

I'm a little stuck now going around in circles and was hoping to get some advice or pushed in the right direction.

Here is the stripped out HTML and javascript.

This is as close as I've got so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post" name="FormName">
        <div>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <div class='mb-3'>
                <input type="text" value="Form Name Here" name="name" maxlength="75" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Group1:</label>
            <div">
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_0" name="ac_0" /> - 0</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_1" name="ac_1" /> - 1</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_2" name="ac_2" /> - 2</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_3" name="ac_3" /> - 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Group2:</label>
            <div">
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_4" name="ac_4" /> - 4</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_5" name="ac_5" /> - 5</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_6" name="ac_6" /> - 6</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_7" name="ac_7" /> - 7</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Group3:</label>
            <div">
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_8" name="ac_8" /> - 8</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_9" name="ac_9" /> - 9</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_10" name="ac_10" /> - 10</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_11" name="ac_11" /> - 11</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_12" name="ac_12" /> - 12</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Group4:</label>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="ac_13" name="ac_13" /> - 13
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Group5:</label>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="ac_14" name="ac_14" /> - 14
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Group6:</label>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="ac_15" name="ac_15" /> - 15
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Group7:</label>
            <div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_16" name="ac_16" /> - 16</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_17" name="ac_17" /> - 17</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_18" name="ac_18" /> - 18</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Access Right" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset Form" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
          window.onload = function() {
    const groups = [
        { master: 'ac_0', checkboxes: ['ac_1', 'ac_2', 'ac_3'] },
        { master: 'ac_4', checkboxes: ['ac_5', 'ac_6', 'ac_7'] },
        { master: 'ac_8', checkboxes: ['ac_9', 'ac_10', 'ac_11', 'ac_12'] },
        { master: 'ac_1', checkboxes: ['ac_2', 'ac_3'] },
        { master: 'ac_5', checkboxes: ['ac_6', 'ac_7'] },
        { master: 'ac_9', checkboxes: ['ac_10', 'ac_11'] }
    ];

    function updateCheckboxes(masterId, checkboxes) {
        const masterCheckbox = document.getElementById(masterId);

        const checked = masterCheckbox.checked;

        checkboxes.forEach(id => {
            const checkbox = document.getElementById(id);
            checkbox.disabled = !checked;
            checkbox.checked = false;
        });

        if (masterId === 'ac_0' && !checked) {
            checkboxes.forEach(id => {
                const checkbox = document.getElementById(id);
                checkbox.disabled = true;
            });
        }
    }

    groups.forEach(group => {
        const masterCheckbox = document.getElementById(group.master);

        masterCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
            updateCheckboxes(group.master, group.checkboxes);
        });

        if (!masterCheckbox.checked) {
            updateCheckboxes(group.master, group.checkboxes);
        }
    });
}


        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Without looking too closely, when a later rule has already been "set" (eg ac_1 set by ac_0 rule) then you need to ignore that second rule.  You can do this two ways 1) check (not tick) the rules before running   2) un-disable all checkboxes then check if the checkbox for the current rule disabled - if it is don't run that rule.   One minor issue with (2)  is that it relies on the UI state, so you may prefer not to take that route

Comment: Alternatively you could run the rules least-significant first (either by running the `groups` in reverse order or by simple reordering the `groups` array - ie run ac_1 before ac_0 then ac_0 will override ac_1 - currently ac1_ is overriding ac_0

Comment: Perhaps if you try to rewrite the rules so that each checkbox has its own rule which determines whether this checkbox should be checked or not - you will either solve the problem or find out that there is an infinite cycle in the rules definitions. You apparently are trying to tackle the problem in a procedural (imperative) way - but I believe the better way is to use the declarative (functional) approach.

Comment: I've managed to get it crudely working and put my answer below. It works!

Once I have tidied it up I'll post that answer. Unless someone beats me to it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to do what I wanted it to do at a very basic level.

I'm just working on now tidying up the code so it's in a more concise and organised way.

Here's what I've done with the function:

```js
window.onload = function(){
            const checkbox_0 = document.getElementById("ac_0");
            const checkbox_1 = document.getElementById("ac_1");
            const checkbox_2 = document.getElementById("ac_2");
            const checkbox_3 = document.getElementById("ac_3");

            const checkbox_4 = document.getElementById("ac_4");
            const checkbox_5 = document.getElementById("ac_5");
            const checkbox_6 = document.getElementById("ac_6");
            const checkbox_7 = document.getElementById("ac_7");

            const checkbox_8 = document.getElementById("ac_8");
            const checkbox_9 = document.getElementById("ac_9");
            const checkbox_10 = document.getElementById("ac_10");
            const checkbox_11 = document.getElementById("ac_11");
            const checkbox_12 = document.getElementById("ac_12");

            function updateCheckboxes0_3(){
                if(checkbox_0.checked){
                    checkbox_1.disabled = false
                    checkbox_2.disabled = false
                    checkbox_3.disabled = false
                }
                else{
                    checkbox_1.disabled = true
                    checkbox_1.checked = false
                    checkbox_2.disabled = true
                    checkbox_2.checked = false
                    checkbox_3.disabled = true
                    checkbox_3.checked = false
                }

                if(checkbox_0.checked && checkbox_1.checked){
                    checkbox_2.disabled = false
                    checkbox_3.disabled = false
                }
                else{
                    checkbox_2.disabled = true
                    checkbox_2.checked = false
                    checkbox_3.disabled = true
                    checkbox_3.checked = false
                }
            }

            function updateCheckboxes4_7(){
                if(checkbox_4.checked){
                    checkbox_5.disabled = false
                    checkbox_6.disabled = false
                    checkbox_7.disabled = false
                }
                else{
                    checkbox_5.disabled = true
                    checkbox_5.checked = false
                    checkbox_6.disabled = true
                    checkbox_6.checked = false
                    checkbox_7.disabled = true
                    checkbox_7.checked = false
                }

                if(checkbox_4.checked && checkbox_5.checked){
                    checkbox_6.disabled = false
                    checkbox_7.disabled = false
                }
                else{
                    checkbox_6.disabled = true
                    checkbox_6.checked = false
                    checkbox_7.disabled = true
                    checkbox_7.checked = false
                }
            }

            function updateCheckboxes8_12(){
                if(checkbox_8.checked){
                    checkbox_9.disabled = false
                    checkbox_10.disabled = false
                    checkbox_11.disabled = false
                    checkbox_12.disabled = false
                }
                else{
                    checkbox_9.disabled = true
                    checkbox_9.checked = false
                    checkbox_10.disabled = true
                    checkbox_10.checked = false
                    checkbox_11.disabled = true
                    checkbox_11.checked = false
                    checkbox_12.disabled = true
                    checkbox_12.checked = false
                }

                if(checkbox_8.checked && checkbox_9.checked){
                    checkbox_10.disabled = false
                    checkbox_11.disabled = false
                }
                else{
                    checkbox_10.disabled = true
                    checkbox_10.checked = false
                    checkbox_11.disabled = true
                    checkbox_11.checked = false
                }
            }

            checkbox_0.addEventListener('change', updateCheckboxes0_3);
            checkbox_1.addEventListener('change', updateCheckboxes0_3);
            checkbox_2.addEventListener('change', updateCheckboxes0_3);
            checkbox_3.addEventListener('change', updateCheckboxes0_3);

            checkbox_4.addEventListener('change', updateCheckboxes4_7);
            checkbox_5.addEventListener('change', updateCheckboxes4_7);
            checkbox_6.addEventListener('change', updateCheckboxes4_7);
            checkbox_7.addEventListener('change', updateCheckboxes4_7);

            checkbox_8.addEventListener('change', updateCheckboxes8_12);
            checkbox_9.addEventListener('change', updateCheckboxes8_12);
            checkbox_10.addEventListener('change', updateCheckboxes8_12);
            checkbox_11.addEventListener('change', updateCheckboxes8_12);
            checkbox_12.addEventListener('change', updateCheckboxes8_12);

            updateCheckboxes0_3();
            updateCheckboxes4_7();
            updateCheckboxes8_12();
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post" name="FormName">
        <div>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <div>
                <inputtype="text" value="Form Name Here" name="name" maxlength="75" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Group1:</label>
            <div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_0" name="ac_0" checked /> - 0</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_1" name="ac_1" checked /> - 1</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_2" name="ac_2" /> - 2</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_3" name="ac_3" checked /> - 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Group2:</label>
            <div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_4" name="ac_4" checked /> - 4</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_5" name="ac_5" /> - 5</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_6" name="ac_6" /> - 6</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_7" name="ac_7" /> - 7</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Group3:</label>
            <div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_8" name="ac_8" checked /> - 8</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_9" name="ac_9" /> - 9</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_10" name="ac_10" /> - 10</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_11" name="ac_11" /> - 11</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_12" name="ac_12" /> - 12</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Group4:</label>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="ac_13" name="ac_13" /> - 13
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Group5:</label>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="ac_14" name="ac_14" /> - 14
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Group6:</label>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="ac_15" name="ac_15" /> - 15
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Group7:</label>
            <div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_16" name="ac_16" /> - 16</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_17" name="ac_17" /> - 17</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="ac_18" name="ac_18" /> - 18</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Access Right" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset Form" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```